# 401 Authorization page when accessing site from some machines

Tags: iis-7

I have a plesk cloud server set up with a demo version of my site.

I can access this from most computers by hitting the correct URL and authenticating myself using the required windows credentials.

From some machines however I am receiving a 401 Unauthorized message when trying to hit the site.

The only thing I can think off is that it maybe going through a proxy on these machines but can;t say for certain and it is just a setting in IIS but I have absolutely no idea which setting?

The site is as ASP.NET application running under IIS7

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Authentication on IIS will never work over proxies apparently.....

[See here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/523ae943-5e6a-4200-9103-9808baa00157.mspx?mfr=true)